# How to connect a button to an input

Tags: html, button, input, alignment

How would I make the button connect to the input, there is an awkward gap I don't know how to fix.

[image: here is the input and button]

```
  #ask {

        padding: 10px  10px 10px 6px;
        font-size:45px;
        background-color:#FAFAFA;
        min-width: 400px;
        padding: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 5px;

  }

#button {
      text-align:center;

      }

 </style>


   <input id="ask" type="text" placeholder = "Ex: how tall is the gateway arch" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Ex: how tall is the gateway arch'"/>
   <input type="image" src="qmb.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="button" height="50.5px" padding = "0px"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS float:left to get input & image side by side.

```
input, img {
    float:left;
}
```

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnj604pr/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input tags in a div like this:

```
<div>
    <input....>
    <input....>
</div>
```

This way the browser will align them for you.

You also might want to consider changing your second input tag to use the button or submit tag.

Comment: is there whitespace in the image you are using?

Comment: You can also use positioning for your image. In the css, give it a position or "relative". Then adjust the top or bottom properties.

Comment: As far as I know there is no white space in the image